# Need help for the SQL Distinct

Tags: sql, distinct

Original table

```
+-- Col 1 --+-- Col 2 --+
+--   1   --+--   a   --+
+--   1   --+--   b   --+
+--   1   --+--   c   --+
+--   2   --+--   d   --+
+--   3   --+--   e   --+
+--   3   --+--   f   --+
+-----------------------+
```

Result :

```
+-- Col 1 --+-- Col 2 --+
+--   1   --+--   a   --+
+--   2   --+--   d   --+
+--   3   --+--   e   --+
+-----------------------+
```

Any idea how to distinct the table?

Comment: For what database?  And what have you tried?

Comment: Did you try and see what happens with `distinct col1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"DISTINCT" applies to every column in the result set.

A "GROUP BY" will provide the result you require, but you need to think about whether "col2" has any real meaning in your result set.

```
 SELECT col1, min(col2) as col2
      FROM T
     GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: no real meaning.i just wan to get an unique record at col 1 and any record from col 2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2
FROM T t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                 FROM T s
                 WHERE t.Col1 = s.Col1 AND t.Col2 > s.Col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have same value in col2 for same values in col1, so result could not be generated by DISTINCT if you are selecting both columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server, with table name is TEST, you can use CROSS APPLY in T-SQL as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1, TEST2.Col2 FROM TEST
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Col2 FROM TEST TEST2
        WHERE TEST2.Col1 = TEST.Col1) TEST2
```